# Scipy ODE errors describing chemical equations

Tags: python, scipy, ode, differential-equations, odeint

I've got a large set of ODEs representing chemical fluxes in a biological system. Where molecules are being reacted, sequestered and cycled. I'm trying to get this to function in such a way as to give me an idea as to how much of certain products can be produced under a series of conditions.

I'm using these packages

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
import pylab as p
```

This is my function

```
def rxn(y,t):
    k1=1         #population coco * rate of photosynthesis 
    k2=0.5      #population methan * rate of reaction 
    k3=0.01  
    i=25   #day shape approximation
    Pe=0.1 #approx photosynthetic efficiency 
    Ce=0.1 #approx calcium carbonate production efficiency  
    x =i*math.sin(math.pi*t/24)**2 
    # x= day night shift

    #Sugar Production  
    r1= x * (y[0]*y[1])  -k1*(y[2]*y[3]) 
    #  R1 ** 2cho3 + 2h+  <-> o2+ 2ch3cooh ***

    # Anaerobic Respiration
    r2= Pe* -k2*(y[4]*y[5]) 
    #  R2 *** ch3cooh      -> co2 + ch4     ***

    # Calcium carbonate production 
    r3= x* Ce * -k3*(y[6]*y[4]*y[7])
    #  Ca + 2hco3     -> Caco3 + co2 + h2o

    dWdt =              +  r3   #Water
    dCdt =       - r2   +  r3   #Carbon Dioxide
    dAdt =   r1  + r2           #Acetate 
    dMdt =       - r2           #Methane
    dOdt = 2*r1                 #Oxygen 
    dCadt=              -  r3   #Calcium
    dCbdt= 2*r1         -2*r3   #Carbonate
    dCacdt=             +  r3   #Calcium carbonate





    return [dWdt,dCdt,dAdt,dMdt,dOdt,dCadt,dCbdt,dCacdt]
```

Then the rest of my code is as follows

```
# Timespan (0 - hours - increment)
tspan=np.arange(0,50,0.1)

#Starting Concentrations 
#y0 = H2o co2 chcooh ch4 o2 ca hco-3 caco3
y0=[100,40,10,10,10,80,70,10]

Conc=odeint(rxn,y0,tspan,full_output = 1,mxstep=5000)

CW = Conc[:,0]
CC = Conc[:,1]
CA = Conc[:,2]
CM = Conc[:,3]
CO = Conc[:,4]
CCa= Conc[:,5]
CCo= Conc[:,6]
CCc= Conc[:,7]

plt.plot(tspan,CC,label='co2')
plt.plot(tspan,CA,label='ch3cooh')
plt.plot(tspan,CM,label='ch4')
plt.plot(tspan,CO,label='o2')
plt.plot(tspan,CCa,label='Ca')
plt.plot(tspan,CCo,label='hco3-')
plt.plot(tspan,CCc,label='caco3')

plt.xlabel("time (hours)")
plt.ylabel("moles")
plt.title("Nutrient Flux?")
plt.legend()

p.show()
```

When this runs I get a multitude of errors to do with both convergence and types. Namely;

```
 lsoda--  at t (=r1) and step size h (=r2), the    
       corrector convergence failed repeatedly       
       or with abs(h) = hmin   ls
      in above,  r1 =  0.3550854455646D+01   r2 =  0.2492601566412D-09
```

and

```
      File "Reaction.py", line 62, in <module>
    CW = Conc[:,0]
TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not tuple
```

I've read what each of these errors means on other stack exchange answers, however, i don't really see how such a simple set of ODEs could be so stiff and I don't really understand where i get the typeerror from either. I am very very new to python (probably evident by now) and I have a feeling this is due to some kind of coding error. I would really appreciate any help solving this.

Comment: Check the signs of the terms in your differential equations.  Here's something that looks questionable to me:  `r2` and `r3` are both negative, and both those reactions produce carbon dioxide.  So why is `dCdt = -r2 + r3`?  Shouldn't it be `dCdt = -r2 - r3`?  (I'm not a chemist; this comment is based on your comments in the code.)

Answer (score 1):

I just decreased the time interval at which the solution is sought and found that for `tspan=np.arange(0,5,0.1)` the solution grows very rapidly with time and reaches `~1e19`. For `tspan=np.arange(0,10,0.1)` it reaches `~1e38`. So probably your solution exponentially tends to infinity and the problem may be in your parameters, initial conditions or equations.

To avoid the second error in your question I just used   `Conc=odeint(rxn,y0,tspan,full_output = 1,mxstep=10000)[0]`
because `odeint` returns tuple `(y, infodict)`, while we need `y` only.

Solutions for `tspan=np.arange(0,10,0.1)`:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since you want the full output, [odeint](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.odeint.html) will return an infodict as well.

```
Conc, info_dict = odeint(rxn, y0, tspan, full_output=1, mxstep=5000)
```

On a side note, maybe you want to have a look on [chemreac](https://github.com/chemreac/chemreac) which is built for your kind of problems.